# Python Class Instance Attributes into HTML template

Tags: python, html

I have a list that collects all instances of a class that were created before. These instances carry attributes such as "value" and an "id". Here is a simplified example:

```
class Test:

  liste = []

  def __init__(self, id, value):
      self.value = value
      self.id    = id
      Test.liste.append(self)

#create two instances:
test1 = Test(0,'G')
test2 = Test(1,'B')
```

Now, I have some html document that I would like to use as a template. Again simplified, it looks as follows:

```html
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="button-container">
       <input class="choice" id='0' value='G'  type='submit'/>
       <input class="choice" id='1' value='B'  type='submit'/>
       <input class="choice" id='2' value=''  type='submit'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I fill out the `value=` in the html document, given the list (liste) has been created, and given the html document in the form below with many class=choice lines (to keep it short, there is only three lines here).

So for the instance test1, with `test1.id=0` and `test1.value='G'` the html line with `id=0` should have `value='G'`. If there is an html line with an `id` equal to a number that doesn't match any of the instance id's, than it should get a default value, e.g. value=''.

Comment: What templating framework are you using?

Comment: @Josh None so far. I'm reading into Genshi but have trouble finding (or understanding) what I need. I'm really completely new to such kind of things and would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you are using [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) and you passed `tests=Test.liste` to your rendering method:

```
{% for test in tests %}
<input class="choice" id='{{ test.id }}' value='{{ test.value }}'  type='submit'/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx here for your answer, I appreciate! I'll take a look into this jinja2. Basically, in my program, liste will have a known amount of instances inside, but the id's and value's of the instances are unpredictable (id = some integer; value = either 'G' or 'B'). Additionally, I have a html document as shown above with a known amount of lines inside (e.g. a line id=0,..,it=20). Once the program has created liste, it has "to take" the html document and fill in the values where instance.id = id in the html document.

Comment: Srry, pressen enter. So since this is very new to me. Do u think jinja2 or something else can handle this? I'm really a bit lost here. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "rendering method"?

Comment: @Tim it is a function from jinja2 that lets you assign a dictionary of values to be used inside of your template. Are you making something web accessible or is this a desktop script?

Comment: Let me try to explain in laymen terms. First, there is a web server. My program will be a lil game (played in a local network). Each user looks at a "matrix" of buttons. This is what the html document is for. However, what each user sees on the buttons ('G','B' or '') is user specifique and this information would be contained inside something like liste. This is why I have one "general template" and then, given the user specific liste, I want to create a html document adopted to the users view. This document will then be sent to the user screen and displayed. I hope this helped?

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Perhaps as a short add on. The id's on the html template are fixed. Only the values are not. Via the html id's the respective html values are connected to the instance in liste id. At least this is how I thought about it:)